# how to block the double execution of the same script in the same directory

Tags: bash, executable

I have created a .sh executable file that generates several files in the working directory/folder that are used by the same script. If it is run twice in the same folder it would be a mess because the loops inside the script would use both new files and those previously created. Is there any option that would block the double execution of the same script in the same folder? Then echo "this operation has been already executed here, change folder"

Comment: you can check for the existence of the files. Wouldn't that solve the issue?

Comment: I believe that it wouldn't work because the script takes input names given by the user, then finds in a folder the files that match the input and use them in a function that generates severals *.bam files. After there's a loop that iterates over all *.bam files created by the previous function to create other files. So even if I would have checked the first step, I would have to change all the loops condition. I thought that there has been a faster alternative

Comment: Wait, but if the names can be different, then there's no problem to begin with, and "running it multiple times from the same directory" is a desirable thing.

Comment: yes, output filenames are different but have the same extension, since my loop is like "for file in *.bam" then all the bam files would go through a loop, old and new files. Maybe, as I'm looping through the input i could use the substring in the loop like for i in "${names[@]}.bam", something like that

Comment: @wildos if you want help with that, I suggest you [edit] your question to describe your current workflow. There are lots of options - such as prefixing the filenames with a unique identifier or timestamp, or placing each set of files in a separate subdirectory etc.

Answer (score 0):

Once the script starts - check does it have a file ".i_am_running". If file does not exist - create it, do the job, delete the file. If it does exist - this is the second instance of the process, exit immediately.

Answer (score 0):

> output filenames are different but have the same extension, since my loop is like "for file in *.bam" then all the bam files would go through a new loop, old one and newone

honestly, then you have already identified your problem and the proper solution (just store the list of files you generated in a variable instead of going throug `*.bam`.

This is not a matter of "elegance"; what you're currently doing is plain buggy.

Comment: ok, I got you. I started using bash less than 1 week ago, so many concepts are new to me. can you be more precise? how could i store the list instead using a loop?

Comment: not *instead* of a loop; instead of the glob `*.bam` when you go through the generated files